# Cannot figure out how the component.service is not the same than the service

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular15

I tried several approaches and I cannot find the problem. This is the furthest I've come:

```
it('should load the current serviceData', fakeAsync( inject([Service1], (service1: Service1) => {
      // spyOn(service1, 'get').and.returnValue(of(mockService1));
      //spyOn(service1, 'get').and.callFake(() => { return of(mockService); });
      
      spyOn(service1, 'get').and.callFake(() => { 
        console.log('get method called');
        return of(mockService1); 
      });

      component.ngOnInit();
      tick(5000);
      fixture.detectChanges();

      expect(component.service2).toEqual(service1);
      expect(service1.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(0);
      expect(component.mockService2).toEqual(mockService1);
      expect(component.showCountdown).toBeFalse();
      expect(component.loading).toBeFalse();
    })));
```

The console.log statement is not reached, but:

```
expect(component.service2).toEqual(service1);
```

Is returning this error:

```
× should load the current campaign
        Chrome Headless 83.0.4103.0 (Windows 10)
      Expected object to have properties
          get: spy on get
      Expected object not to have properties
          url: 'https://localhost:9091/data/dataService2.json'
      Error: Expected object to have properties
          get: spy on get
      Expected object not to have properties
          url: 'https://localhost:9091/data/dataService2.json'
          at <Jasmine>
          at UserContext.apply (src/app/features/home/home.component.spec.ts:88:41)
          at TestBedImpl.execute (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/testing.mjs:24217:19)
          at UserContext.<anonymous> (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/testing.mjs:24434:24)
```

I think my problem could be around this, but I am not able to find the reason of that. Please, any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, forcing to the service to be the exactly the same service than the component works for me.

```
it('example', fakeAsync(inject([Service1], (service1: Service1) => {
      spyOn(service1, 'get').and.callFake(() => {
        return of(mockService1);
      });
.......
component = new HomeComponent(sanitazer, service1, router, toastrService);
......
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This won't be a complete answer but it should help you get started.
This is the main issue:

```
Expected object to have properties
          get: spy on get
Expected object not to have properties
          url: 'https://localhost:9091/data/dataService2.json'
```

One of them has those properties, the other one does not.

You could log them out to see which properties they have right before the `expect`.

```
it('should load the current serviceData', fakeAsync( inject([Service1], (service1: Service1) => {
      // spyOn(service1, 'get').and.returnValue(of(mockService1));
      //spyOn(service1, 'get').and.callFake(() => { return of(mockService); });
      
      spyOn(service1, 'get').and.callFake(() => { 
        console.log('get method called');
        return of(mockService1); 
      });

      component.ngOnInit();
      tick(5000);
      fixture.detectChanges();

      // !! Add these logs and see the difference between them.
      console.log('Service 1: ', service1);
      console.log('Service 2: ', service2);

      expect(component.service2).toEqual(service1);
      expect(service1.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(0);
      expect(component.mockService2).toEqual(mockService1);
      expect(component.showCountdown).toBeFalse();
      expect(component.loading).toBeFalse();
    })));
```